# Have you encountered this error message before when trying to stop the Pixel 3 API 28 emulator?

Tags: android, runtime-error, android-virtual-device, avd-manager, avdepthdata

unable to stop pixel 3 api 28 an error occurred stopping pixel 3 api 28. to stop the device, try manually closing the picel 3 api 28 emulator windows

I have try many times to run AVD in Android studio while writing a code of making an app but it can't work.